# Compile error on print statement because I have a bar button print

Tags: swift, printing

```
let cat = "image String length \(imageString?.utf8.count ?? 22 )"
print(cat)
```

I get a error on the print line.

> Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument UIBarButtonItem

I do have a action print

```
@IBAction func print(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
```

Must I change the action or is there away around this.

Comment: The question is not clear. Try to add more details about your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This tells the complier that you are calling `print` defined by the Swift language.

```
Swift.print(cat)
```